# How to create a channel in Opa

Tags: opa

Once again extending "hello_chat" is haunting me :-)

What I'm trying to do is to ask for a username and a room name to join in and be able to notify users on a room about new users joining in using two distinct `channel`s per room; one for user messages (normal chat) and the other for server notices (such as 'User X joined the room').

[Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/5dF8Fqg8) I've got so far.  Obviously `join_room()` has a problem:  I don't know how to create a `channel` to `add` it to a `network`.

I'd appreciate any hint/help.  TIA,

--
Bahman

Answer (score 2):

I think it's very strange to create new rooms, every time a user joins the chat.

```
  usernet = Network.cloud("CHAT_USER_NETWORK")
  servernet = Network.cloud("CHAT_SERVER_NETWORK")
```

As you can see on our example, the room is created at toplevel, in order to have only one room for the whole server. (but you can cerate two rooms if you want)

I did not look at your whole code, but this is a first step i guess.

You can have a look at my fork on GitHub :

https://github.com/Aqua-Ye/OpaChat

Comment: To my understanding [Opa documentation on `Network.cloud`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#network.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Network.cloud) means that it doesn't matter how many times same cloud is created since it can be shared between servers.  Am I right?   BTW, thanks a lot for the link to your own code.  Much appreciated.